# Last TreeMap element skipped in JSP view while looping

Tags: jsp, jstl, treemap

I am passing a TreeMap object in the modelview object. Issue is while looping through the map using below JSTL code in JSP, the last element is getting skipped. So for instance, if I pass 93 elements in the map, only 92 values are visible.I debugged the code to check the JSP variable headerMap content in the runtime and found all the values present there but in JSP it does not print the last element. Can anybody highlight what is wrong here.

```
<c:forEach items="${headerMap}" var="header" varStatus="headerIndex">
    <th class="admin-search-result-th">${headerMap[headerIndex.index]}</th>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are iterating through a Map, all you have to

```
<c:forEach items="${headerMap}" var="header">
    <th class="admin-search-result-th">${header.value}</th> 
</c:forEach>
```

Accessing the map in the fashion you have done

> ${headerMap[headerIndex.index]}

will actually fetch you the value in the Map corresponding to a key.

`${mapVariable['key']}` fetches the value corresponding to the 'key' from the map. Do you get a null (or blank value) anywhere? Assuming that you keys are all int values corresponding to indexes, I suspect one of the key doesnt fit this criteria and has a different value.

Comment: Initially, I tried in this fashion only. It yielded the same result. Further, there is no blank or null key in the Map object. I have already diagnosis that and the value is always the last element that is skipped.

{0=countryCode, 1=currencyCode, ..............90=insNationality, 91=companyName, 92=designation} . Here the 92th element is not getting rendered on to the jsp page even when the jsp variable headerMap has the value .

Comment: The index value for 92 elements start from 0 and go up to 91 (0 to 91). You will never get a value of 92 from the index. Use the key and value - that will work.

Comment: No, it was not the case. Rather something similar to your first reply was the reason. The key no 53 was altogether missing in the Map object and last value was getting shifted because of that. Nevertheless thanks a lot for your response.